# Async Operation vs Async Network task?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsurlsessiondatatask

Having the common scenario of needing to asynchronously call a RESTful Web Service to get a JSON content, and then parsing that JSON response to create some data model entities. This process could be cancelled/resumed. I'm not completely sure of which the best approach would be:

- Implementing an `Operation` for the network call and another `Operation` for the JSON parsing and setting a dependency between both operations (the JSON output from the former being the data input of the latter). Then, adding those operations to a `OperationQueue`.
- Using a `URLSession` and `URLSessionDataTask` to perform the network call, and the JSON parsing in its callback.

Or maybe another different and better way?

**EDIT:** In my scenario, I don't need to perform concurrent network calls. If I need to call the service with different params, I should be able to stop the previous network task if necessary, and start the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most simple cases, the answer is just an URLSession, but if it is complicated, as your seems to be, then Operation is a useful tool. This precise use case is discussed at length in [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226).

Comment: Thank you. I only need to perform that 2 tasks, network call + JSON response parsing, and no concurrency needed. If I need a new network call, I just need to stop the previous one if in progress and start the new one. That would make the URLSession option more suitable?

Comment: Yes; you can use `invalidateAndCancel()` to cancel an existing session. You just need to keep track of it.